# How to dynamically customize .net .config files

Tags: .net, sql-server-2008, web-config, app-config, transformation

I'm part of a small development team and we are currently moving from a model where we share the same development database to a model where we all have our own personal development databases..

Because of this, we are trying to figure out how to manage the web and app .config files to accommodate the individual databases.  Clearly we want to avoid the situation where everyone will need to manually change the connection string to point to their own database then remember to change it back before checking back in!

I'm sure this is a very common problem that faces almost all development teams.  Despite this, I cannot find any solutions to this problem.

I am familiar with web.config transformations using xdt syntax and while this helps with the modification of the files, it doesn't (as far as I know) provide a way to inject in an external parameter value.  For example, we would need the transformation to detect the current user, and replace the database name in the .config with one containing their username.

So,  how to you solve this problem in your development team?

Thanks.

Edit:

Sorry, I missed a fairly important piece of information that prevents these answers from being acceptable.  As a company, we all work remotely and remote desktop into our development environment.  We effectively have one (powerful) development machine that all developers rdp into and use simultaneously.  Therefore, using aliases or modifying host files etc would apply to all users equally and not provide the individual customization necessary.  The SQL instance is already a local instance, it is just a local instance on the machine that is used by all developers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can suggest two ways of doing this.

1. Use the same alias for your database server name so that connection strings will be identical, you can do this by putting the following line into your hosts file:

   127.0.0.1   DBSERVER
2. Put your connection strings into external file and don't add it to the source control. For the staging and release configurations you can add required connection strings through web config transformations.

In the second case your web.config will look like this:

```
<connectionStrings configSource="connectionStrings.config"></connectionStrings>
```

EDIT:
Where `connectionStrings.config` file is placed in the same folder but is added to ignore list under source control so that each developer will have his own copy of this file and his changes will not affect other developers. To simplify things you can create a `connectionStrings.config.default` file that can be used as a template so that when new developer joins the project he will create his own copy of `connectionStrings.config` based on this file with default values.

Comment: Thanks, please see my Edit which explains why this doesn't help for our situation.

Comment: OK, I see. But why don't you like the second approach? As far as I understand though working on the same computer developers have their own copy of source code, don't they?

Comment: Yes but its the same problem,  each developer will have to customise the source code to point to their own individual connection file.  That solution effectively moves the problem from the web.config file to another new file.   -- Perhaps I'm not understanding this,  could you explain more about how you would set up these external files, and how you would get the source to access them.  Thanks!

Comment: I've added more detailed description of my approach. Basically you are right - the problem is moved to another file and is only partially solved. However every developer will need to manually create it only once and there will be no need to change it back before checking back in.

Answer (score 0):

An option could be using named connection strings and having these defined in machine.config instead of web.config.

Comment: Thanks,  please see my Edit to the question that explains why modifying the machine.config wont help in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

A common solution to this problem is to have the development database on each users development machine, so that you can have the same connection string for everyone, e.g. for SQL Server it will be something like:

```
connectionString="data source=.\SQLExpress;..."
```

When you do this you want each developer to have the latest database, so you should really look at Visual Studio 2010 database projects, which make it really easy (SQL Server only though).

Comment: Thanks,  please see my Edit which explains why this doesn't help for our situation.

Answer (score 0):

The technique we use to is to standardise database names, server name (no named instances), username and passwords on the development machines.

So if the product codename is Aero we'd use

> server=(local);database=aero;uid=aero;password=password

For dev environments security isn't important but consistency is, and this technique avoids checking out and breaking other people's app/web.configs.

Comment: Thanks, please see my Edit to the question which explains why this approach isn't useful in our situation.

Answer (score 0):

Although we are using web.config transformations to define used databases (local dev, test, release), every developer can use local SQL server if needed. We are doing that by setting SQL server alias, web config connection string is the same and developers set alias on their machines.

For example we have all set "tester1" in web.config and then developers set alias to their local SQL servers, here is the image :

[image]

Comment: Thanks, please see my Edit which explains why this doesn't help for our situation.